# Cannot set file type of fixtures in Cypress reply intercepts

Tags: cypress, midi, cypress-intercept

I'm trying to stub a midi file in a Cypress intercept. From the URL I am deriving a fixture to load and use in the reply. I am doing something like:

```
cy.intercept("**/MIDI/*", (req) => {
  const fixtureName = get_last_part_of(req.url)  // This will yield a fixture like 1.mid
  req.reply( {
    headers: {
      'content-type': "audio/sp-midi"
    },
    fixture: "midi/" + fixtureName
  })
```

When I load this file I get an error in the browser logs about an invalid MIDI file:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Bad MIDI file.  Expected 'MTrk', got: 'MTr'
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:8576:21)
    at polyfills.js:8485:11
```

I *think* this is because the `1.mid` is treated as `utf-8`, but I want it to be treated as `binary`. Is there a way to specify this in the `reply`?

I've tried reading the file directly in the intercept but because I am using cy.visit that invokes the intercept, I am getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

There are some clues here [Fixture - Default Encoding](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Encoding). The "known extensions" list doesn't include `mid`, and the following paragraph confirms that the default would be `utf8`.

From here [Intercept - StaticResponse objects](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#StaticResponse-objects)

> Serve a fixture as the HTTP response body (allowed when body is omitted). Read the contents with an encoding other than the default for the file type, pass the fixture like `path,encoding`.

This might work:

```js
cy.intercept("**/MIDI/*", (req) => {
  const fixtureName = get_last_part_of(req.url)  // This will yield a fixture like 1.mid
  req.reply( {
    headers: {
      'content-type': "audio/sp-midi"
    },
    fixture:  `midi/${fixtureName},binary`
  })
```

---

**Using a sample midi**

Here's a passing test using a very simple test page, following the information given in the question.

**Sample page**

```html
<script>
  fetch('https://some-domain/api/MIDI/1.mid')
</script>
```

**Test**

```js
cy.intercept('**/MIDI/*', (req) => {
  const fixtureName = req.url.split('/').pop()
  req.reply( {
    headers: {
      'content-type': "audio/sp-midi"
    },
    fixture:  `midi/${fixtureName},binary`
  })
}).as('midi')

cy.visit('midi.html')

cy.wait('@midi')
```

No error occurs, which makes me think you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I should have added the error message that I am getting is:
```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Bad MIDI file.  Expected 'MTrk', got: 'MTr'
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:8576:21)
```

Comment: The error actually comes from `tone.js` where it is trying to parse the MIDI. The reason I think it is an encoding error is because the file plays fine in a MIDI player, and the error doesn't occur if I remove the interceptor and get it from the link. I'll try to isolate a simple example that show's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I now have an answer to this, though I don't completely understand what is happening. Instead of using the `binary` encoding, I have to use `null`. So, if I do

```
cy.intercept('**/MIDI/*', (req) => {
  const fixtureName = req.url.split('/').pop()
  req.reply( {
    headers: {
      'content-type': "audio/sp-midi"
    },
    fixture:  `midi/${fixtureName},null`
  })
})
```

I no longer get the MIDI error.

The way that I discovered this was to copy the resource as an asset in the app I was testing, and have the intercept request the MIDI file from there. I noticed that the length of the body was 191. Then, I compared the response loaded from the intercepted fixture, and noticed that it was 220. The same thing was happening when I checked the length using the result of `cy.readFile(<fixturefile>, 'binary')`, until I set `null` encoding. This creates a buffer that is used in the body of the message, rather than a "binary" representation of it.